# Taco stops in the middle of livereload

Tags: cordova, gulp, source-maps, taco

I recently set up my project with a gulp system to compile and minify (with sourcemaps) jade, stylus, and es6 from a separate `/src` folder into `/www`. I am endeavoring to use TACO for livereload, but whenever one of these files is changed (I believe only those requiring sourcemaps), the following error occurs:

> [BS] File changed: {myprojectdirectory}\www\app\maps\index.js.map
>    - An error occurred: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '{myprojectdirectory}\platforms\android\assets\www\index.html'

Looking into the platform folder, index.html (and others) is indeed missing. Is there a proper way to let TACO know when gulp is done, or do I need to operate without sourcemaps?

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing bug on TACO for this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TACO/issues/246

It is usually caused have a file open by different processes. Some folks have had success by turning off the autosave feature of their code editor.